# How to make a function that counts the amount of equal values (in random position) inside a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, count

I need to find how many people with the same name are sitting in certain chairs, chairs that are organized in a matrix.

I made a small try, but I can`t get it to work. I know I'm basically doing "If 2 is 2, count++", but I don't know what other therms to use.

This count should be 2, because there are two slots with the same data inside of them. (Maiz in 0,1 and 1,0)

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
public class pru {
public static void main (String[] args){
    String ejnombre[][]=new String[][]{
                        {"Juan", "Maiz"},
                        {"Maiz", "Luis"},
    };
    int count=0;
    for (int i=0; i<ejnombre.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
            if (ejnombre[i][j]==ejnombre[i][j]){
                count++;
            }

        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HashMap with key-value pair for name-count of occurences. Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < ejnombre.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ejnombre.length; j++) {
                incrementCountForName(hm, ejnombre[i][j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(hm));
```

With this method. Here name exists in map you increment value count, if it doesn't you add the name to the map with value count of 1.

```
public static HashMap<String, Integer> incrementCountForName(HashMap<String, Integer> hm, String name) {
        if (hm.containsKey(name)) {
            int count = hm.get(name);
            hm.put(name, count + 1);
        } else {
            hm.put(name, 1);
        }
        return hm;
    }
```